# Why does the neutral hydrogen velocity have this characteristic behavior in the galactic plane?

Tags: radio-astronomy, data-analysis, galactic-dynamics, velocity

The recently released map of galactic neutral hydrogen density and velocity is really beautiful. The work has been relased by the [HI4PI collaboration](http://www.icrar.org/hi4pi/) (HI = neutral hydrogen, $4\pi$ = complete spherical coverage).

My question is fairly simple. Looking at the image near the galactic plane, why do I see near the center a green bump on the left and a blue bump on the right, then near the edges of the image a much stronger blue bump on the left and a green bump on the right. In other words, there is a major and a minor peak in the positive radial velocity gas, and a major and a minor peak in the negative radial velocity gas.

Does this have some simple geometrical explanation?

[image]

[image]

**above x2:** neutral hydrogen density/velocity map [from here](http://www.icrar.org/hi4pi/) with inset indicating color scale expanded.

[image]

**above:** for those who can not distinguish the green and blue in the image, this plots the average green (solid) and blue (dashed) intensity within the central equatorial band.

There is a nice article at [phys.org](http://phys.org/news/2016-10-scientists-milky.html) with a video, which can also be [seen in YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2mgpsTFuV8). It shows the intensity of HI as a cut in radial velocity is slowly scanned through the data set.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2mgpsTFuV8

Since the stackexchange YouTube option is not turned on in astronomy stackexchange, here is a GIF of screenshots at -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, and 30 km/sec:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is detailed in depth in [this pdf](http://euhou.obspm.fr/public/Milky_Way_Rotation_A4.pdf), which contains the following diagram:

[image]

Some key quantities:

- $R_0$: Distance from the observer to the center of the Milky Way
- $R$: Distance from target gas to the center of the Milky Way
- $V_0$: Velocity of the observer with respect to a certain reference frame
- $V$: Velocity of target gas with respect to the same reference frame
- $l$: Angle between $R_0$ and $\mathbf{SM}$, the distance to the gas

When measuring the radial velocity, we look for the projection of $V$ onto our line of sight. Some geometry results in the relation
$$V_r=V_0\left(\frac{R_0}{R}-1\right)\sin l$$
for the radial velocity $V_r$, assuming $V\approx V_0$ (which is not always true!). The $\sin l$ term, in addition to the asymmetrical rotation of the Milky Way, leads to the peculiar data you asked about.

Comment: OK I need a day to dig into this. What caught my eye is the $2\theta$-ness of the distribution - two blues and two greens per 360 degrees. The $sin(l)$ isn't getting me there, but I need to look again.

Comment: @uhoh The reason for that is the factor of $\left(\frac{R_0}{R}-1\right)$, which creates another zero at $R_0=R$ and on either side of that. See several slides [here](https://www.astro.rug.nl/~sctrager/teaching/PoG/2012/HIintheMW.pdf).

Comment: Oh right!! OK I've got it. Those are beautiful slides by the way - someone has put a lot of work into them! This will keep me busy for a while, thanks!